# How can I add a vector to a list of vectors in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I'm new to R. In the code I need to create a list of vectors(like tuples in python), which is named e. I find I cannot add new element, i.e. a vector to the list, in this way: e[i]<-c(5,3); the result shows only 5 is added to the list and there is a warning message: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Use double square brackets: `e[[4]]<-c(5,3)`.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Search for "append", try: `c(e, list(c(5,3)))` or `append(e, list(c(5,3)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `list` when with `[`

```
e[4] <- list(c(5, 3))
```

since `[` store data in terms of `list` in your case.

---

Or just `[[` for assignment

```
e[[4]] <- c(5,3)
```

You can type `?[` and read for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with double bracket for lists as **@Nicola** suggested in comments:

```
#Data
e <- list(c(0,1),c(1,3),c(4,0))
#Add
e[[4]] <- c(5,3)
```

Output:

```
e
[[1]]
[1] 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 0

[[4]]
[1] 5 3
```

It can also work:

```
#Code2
e <- c(e,list(c(5,3)))
```